# I want to build an AR tool to place and store text files in a virtual space

Tags: ios, python-3.x, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

It's called a memory palace (Read: 'Moonwalking with Einstein') it's an ancient tool used to memorize, in my case coding concepts and Spanish and Indonesian phrases.

I'm learning python now, but I'm not really sure what direction to move in and what stack should be used to build a project like this. it wouldn't be too complex, I just want to store and save "text files" in a virtual space like my bedroom or on my favorite hikes.

If anyone has insights or suggestions it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the two most common AR frameworks, on mobile devices anyway, at the moment are ARKit for iOS devices and ARCore for Android devices.

I am sure you can find comparisons of the strengths and weaknesses of each one but it is likely your choice will be determined by the type of device you have.

In either case, it sounds like you want to have 'places' you can return to over time and see your stored content. For this you could build on some common techniques:

- link the AR object to some sort of image in the real world and when this image is recognised by the AR app, launch your AR object, in your case a text file.
- use 'Cloud Anchors' - these are essentially anchors for AR objects that can persist over time, when you close the app and come back to it later, and even be shared between users on different devices.

You can find more information on cloud Anchors at the link below, including information on using them with iOS and on Android:

- https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android